# How to Apply a logic to a subset of rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

In this problem, I am trying to understand when an alert should be generated based on 'value'.

If previous 5 values are above 10, then an alert is created. The alert continues to stay active till the value goes below 7.5. Now, once the alert is no longer active and it reaches a stage where previous 5 values are above 10, then an alert is created again.

Here is the logic I am using to do this:

```
NUM_PREV_ROWS = 5
PREV_5_THRESHOLD = 10.0
PREV_THRESHOLD = 7.5

d = {'device': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
                    'a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b',
                    'b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'] , 
     'value': [11,11,11,11,11,11,11,8,9,11,11,11,11,11,8,9,6,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,8,9,11,11,11,11,11,8,9,6,11,11,11,11,11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['prev>10'] = df['value']>PREV_5_THRESHOLD
df['prev5>10'] = df['prev>10'].rolling(NUM_PREV_ROWS).sum()
df['prev>7.5'] = df['value']>PREV_THRESHOLD 

alert = False
alert_series = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1]['prev5>10']==NUM_PREV_ROWS:
        alert = True
    if row[1]['prev>7.5']==False:
        alert = False
    alert_series.append(alert)

df['alert'] = alert_series
```

The problem is that the loop should restart when a new device is encountered (in this case, it should first run for A and then run over B once it comes across that device). How can I do this?

This is the output with current logic:

```
print(df)

    value  prev>10  prev5>10  prev>7.5  alert
a      11     True       NaN      True  False
a      11     True       NaN      True  False
a      11     True       NaN      True  False
a      11     True       NaN      True  False
a      11     True       5.0      True   True
a      11     True       5.0      True   True
a      11     True       5.0      True   True
a       8    False       4.0      True   True
a       9    False       3.0      True   True
a      11     True       3.0      True   True
a     11     True       3.0      True   True
a     11     True       3.0      True   True
a     11     True       4.0      True   True
a     11     True       5.0      True   True
a      8    False       4.0      True   True
a      9    False       3.0      True   True
a      6    False       2.0     False  False
a     11     True       2.0      True  False
a     11     True       2.0      True  False
a     11     True       3.0      True  False
a     11     True       4.0      True  False
a     11     True       5.0      True   True
b      11     True      5.0      True  True
b      11     True      5.0     True  True
b      11     True      5.0      True  True
b      11     True      5.0      True  True
b      11     True       5.0      True   True
b      11     True       5.0      True   True
b      11     True       5.0      True   True
b       8    False       4.0      True   True
b       9    False       3.0      True   True
b      11     True       3.0      True   True
b     11     True       3.0      True   True
b     11     True       3.0      True   True
b     11     True       4.0      True   True
b     11     True       5.0      True   True
b      8    False       4.0      True   True
b      9    False       3.0      True   True
b      6    False       2.0     False  False
b     11     True       2.0      True  False
b     11     True       2.0      True  False
b     11     True       3.0      True  False
b     11     True       4.0      True  False
b     11     True       5.0      True   True
```

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: I'd group by device, then change your logic to use pandas' `rolling' to apply a function to identify the alerts

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if this is the best way, but what about using `groupby`to reset the loop?

```py
def f(df):

    alert = False
    alert_series = []
    for row in df.iterrows():
        if row[1]['prev5>10']==NUM_PREV_ROWS:
            alert = True
        if row[1]['prev>7.5']==False:
            alert = False
        alert_series.append(alert)

    return pd.DataFrame({'alert': alert_series})

df['alert'] = df.groupby("device").apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a method that does the parsing for a block. I tried a different, vectorized method:

```
def larger_than_threshold(
    data,
    previous_5_threshold=PREV_5_THRESHOLD,
    amount=NUM_PREV_ROWS,
    previous_threshold=PREV_THRESHOLD,
):
    prev5_over_limit = (
        ((data > previous_5_threshold).rolling(amount).sum() == amount)
        .astype(int)
        .diff()
        == 1
    ).replace({False: None})
    prev_under_threshold = (data < previous_threshold)

    prev5_over_limit[prev_under_threshold] = False

    return prev5_over_limit.fillna(method="ffill").fillna(False)
```

This accepts the `value` Series of your data

You can also use your iterative method here instead.

Then you can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html) to apply this to each separate device

```
df["alert"] = df.groupby("device").transform(larger_than_threshold)
```